# Script to automate Raid0 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, scripting, startup, raid0

Could someone point me to a script that I can run upon startup to create a Raid0 drive on windows server 2008.  The inputs would be the drive letters of two drives to use for the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you're going to be using the [DISKPART](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770877%28WS.10%29.aspx) command, but you're going to have to figure out the exact details yourself.